# on itunes connect, does units represent no of downloads of my application in particular country?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

when I see sales and trend report through itunes connect for my application,
it shows fileds like  artist ,title . units etc...
does units represent no of downloads of my application in particular country?
how can I know.how many times my applications have been downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Important Data are:

- Artist / Show = YOU (Developper)
- Title / Episode / Season = YOUR APP
- Units = NUMBER OF DOWNLOAD
- Royalty Price = MONEY YOU'LL GET
- Country Code
  = COUNTRY OF APPSTORE USER

Do the sum of all “Units” to know how many your app has been downloaded.